# laravel- Concatenate object class name with string

Tags: string, laravel, object, laravel-5, concatenation

How can I Concatenate object class name and string in laravel blade

thanks in Advance.

$lang ='en';
$news[0]->{'n_heading_'.$lang};

Answer (score 0):

In your question I am not seeing any class name. But if you are facing problem to do some php operation in your blade as you have shown in question question. Then:

You can do this using `@php` tag.

In your `.blade.php` file you can do the operation as below:

```
@php
  $lang ='en'; 
  $concatenated = $news[0]->{'n_heading_'.$lang};
@endphp
```

Comment: Please explain clearly, what problem you are facing. What you are expecting. I will update my answer based on your question. You said you want to concat object class name with string. But where is your object class name in your question.